# Get a specific Wicket Component within a Page

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

What's the way to find a specific (known wicket id) Wicket Component within a Page regarding less effort performance?

Comment: define best. define find.

Comment: define specific - what criteria must it match?

Comment: best = less effort performance, find = get, and specific = known wicket id

Comment: If you know the whole path to the component then for sure use the `get()` method from my answer. Otherwise you have to go with `visitChildren()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your options are:

- The [get()](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) method of the component which searches for a
  component at a specific path.
- An [iterator()](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/MarkupContainer.html#iterator%28%29) on the  MarkupContainer which has all his children.
- Use the [visitChildren()](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/MarkupContainer.html#visitChildren%28%29) that has all children and grandchildren of a
  MarkupContainer. `visitChildren()` returns [ComponentHierachyIterator](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/util/iterator/ComponentHierarchyIterator.html) which in turn has a method which has a method [filterById()](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/util/iterator/ComponentHierarchyIterator.html#filterById%28java.lang.String%29) that returns another `ComponentHierachyIterator` with the filtered component(s).

Comment: Links are broken.

Comment: The `ComponentHierachyIterator` is deprecated.